# MC34063 9v to 5v doesn't give expected voltage

Tags: voltage-regulator, switching-regulator

I'm trying to make a 9v to 5v step-down voltage regulator using MC34063
I used an [online calculator](http://www.bobtech.ro/tutoriale/componente-electronice/43-calculator-online-mc34063a-mc34063-step-down-step-up-inverter) for the values and assembled this schematic for stepdown config:
[image]

The calculator gave me these values (for Vin=9, Vout=5, Iout=750, Vripple=1, Fmin=100):

```
Ct=257 pF
Ipk=1500 mA
Rsc=0.2 Ohm
Lmin=13 uH
Co=1875 uF
R1=1k R2=3k (5V)
```

I used a 1800uF capacitor and 10mH inductor but on the output I'm measuring 0.8V instead of 5v with voltmeter
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is your duty cycle, in the calculator they use 50% of duty cycle (based on the datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/mc33063a.pdf page 16)

Comment: Possible issues I see: Can the the inductors you used handle the current ? Note that the 13 uH inductor needs to be one with thick wire and a core. Same for the extra filter inductor. Is the C0 capacitor a low ESR type ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume by 10mH (10,000uH) you actually mean 10uH.

10uH is *way* too low an inductance for the MC34063. You should be getting numbers more like 100-200uH.

Try an 'official' XLS [spreadsheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MC34063%20DWS.XLS) from Onsemi.

I get more like a 170uH inductance, and maximum output current more than 500mA if you can stand 0.56W dissipation from the chip alone. Efficiency about 52%.

You need an inductor that will not saturate with 0.55A current.

[image]